# How do I deform faces in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I would like to combine a human face with a cartoon one as shown in the Beavis & Butthead picture on this [site](http://screwedus.com/2010/03/harry-markopolos-50-billion-dollar-failure/):

[image: bush and guy who hunts people with buckshot as beavis and butthead]

I'm not sure what the technique is called, if there is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the third picture. You can use Filters->Distort->IWarp in order to grow, shrink, and move portions of the picture in order to make it resemble a cartoon. It definitely has some major limitations. It would be nice if those features were more integrated into the main Gimp tools instead of opening another window in order to make the changes. The lack of ctrl-z is also a major limitation. It should do what you want though.

I recommend making the window very large and then pressing reset to start out.

Comment: Yes 3rd picture.